# Merge 2 dictionaries based on specific features

Tags: python, json, dictionary

With 2 json file I am trying to merge certain features of one into the other. I converted the json into dictionaries I am trying to merge features from 1 dictionary into another. However I want specific features of one dictionary to merege with the other but not overwrite the initial values

```
Dictionary A: [{a:1,b:2,f:10},{a:2,b:4,f:10}]
Dictionary B: [{f:1,g:1,k:1},{f:2,g:2,k:1}]
```

Desired:

```
Dictionary C:[{a:1,b:2,f:10,g:1,k:1},{a:2,b:4,f:10,g:2,k:1}]
```

```
Loop through all dictionaries simultaneously
 for x,y in zip(A,B):
     x["g"]= y["g"]
     x["k"]= y["k"]
```

Comment: How are you getting your desired results? there is no `'b': 1` pair in any of the input dicts? You could just loop through both lists simultaneously and union them: `C = [x | y for x, y in zip(A, B)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will preserve the order and not overwrite any duplicate keys in A.

```py
lst_a =  [{'a':1,'b':2,'f':10},{'a':2,'b':4,'f':10}]
lst_b = [{'f':1,'g':1,'k':1},{'f':2,'g':2,'k':1}]

lst_c = []
    
for dict_a,dict_b in zip(lst_a,lst_b):
    dict_b = {k:v for k,v in dict_b.items() if k not in dict_a}
    lst_c.append(dict_a | dict_b)

print(lst_c)
```

Comment: And this wont overwrite everything in list a right? @meg hidey

Comment: ....no it won't

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate using `zip` then combine the dictionaries and filter out the keys that you don't want, you can use comprehension:

```py
# Python 3.9+
>>> [y|x for x,y in zip(A, B)]

# output:
[{'f': 10, 'g': 1, 'k': 1, 'a': 1, 'b': 2}, 
{'f': 10, 'g': 2, 'k': 1, 'a': 2, 'b': 4}]
```

Comment: Can I use this if as [{k:v for k,v in (x|y).items() if k='g'} for x,y in zip(A, B)]  and then another loop for [{k:v for k,v in (x|y).items() if k=k} for x,y in zip(A, B)] , if B has more than 3 keys in the dictionary

Comment: I would like to only merge the specific features

Comment: That's already taken care of by `if k!='f'` you can modify it on need basis like `k=='g'` or `not k in ('a', 'b', 'c',)` etc.

Comment: Does this handle the case of A= j,k,l and b=j,f,b and it would merge lets say we want b, and not overwrite j?

Comment: The OP wants to merge two dictionaries and keep their order, where the first occurrence of the key does not get overridden by subsequent duplicate keys that appear. e.g in the OP, `f` is mapped to 10 not 1.

Comment: @meghidey The question was updated later

Comment: @meghidey see the updated answer

Comment: @user18774110 you can look at the updated answer

Comment: order is not retained

Comment: @meghidey I've included the output for the code

Comment: but I am working with nested dictionaries.  Since [{a,b,c},{a,b,c}]